# NSString returns empty with WebView Innerhtml

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview, nsstring

I'm creating an app that relies on HTML5 and my goal is 'simply' to save the contents of a specific div by running a Javascript function. I've been searching everywhere and I cannot seem to find a good example to help me further or even getting started. I'm hoping you guys could help me point towards the right direction.

Ben Taylor on twitter recently gave me starting code.

```
NSString *html = [yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('NSSidebar').innerHTML"];
NSLog(@"contents:%@",html);
```

The log returns empty. Now it may be because the webview has not been properly loaded in order to have the string to find the 'some-element' div. My current code would be:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:()myWebView {

    NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index"
                                                         ofType:@"html"
                                                    inDirectory:@""];

    NSURL* fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
    [[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];

    NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('NSSidebar'.innerHTML"];
    NSLog(@"contents:%@",html);

}
```

Comment: Is `getElementById('NSSidebar'.innerHTML` a typo or actually the code? It should be `getElementById('NSSidebar').innerHTML` (note the extra parenthesis).

Answer (score 0):

Two mistakes:

1. You have a syntax error: a closing parenthesis is missing.
2. You need to call `.toString()` on the returned object.

Like this:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('NSSidebar').innerHTML.toString()"];
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the 2 mistakes. I've corrected them and I still get empty.

2013-08-07 13:15:30.116 StampReady[2342:303] strtil:

Comment: @user2660308 Then your `NSSidebar` element is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I set up a test project with your code and an index file with a menu side bar with the same id.

I was getting the same results.

I then looked at apples [Webkit Objective -C Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/JavaScriptFromObjC.html)

Which had an couple of examples on how to get the "location.href" using the *frameworks*  "**windowScriptObject**"

I adapted it for the getElement..   and it works.

```
    id win = [_webView windowScriptObject];


 NSString *html = [win evaluateWebScript:@"document.getElementById(\"NSSidebar\").innerHTML"];

     NSLog(@"html:\n%@",html);

    NSString *htmlText = [win evaluateWebScript:@"document.getElementById(\"NSSidebar\").innerText"];

    NSLog(@"htmlText:\n %@",htmlText);
```